# Image gallery loading images from an external server

Tags: php, image, gallery, external

I am trying to make a php image gallery where the script has to the following things:

1. Connect to external server (http/ftp)
2. scan directory "highres"
3. load images from directory "lowres" with same image name.
4. save low-res images on local folder
5. Show low-res images in gallery
6. Download button for the high-res image

Can anyone point me into the right direction cause i dont know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at FTP with PHP and start with reading out the files in the Folder [FTP Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/de/book.ftp.php)

Then use [ftp_get()](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.ftp-get.php) to download the first Image and resize it with help of the [GDlib](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php), here is a [tutorial](http://icant.co.uk/articles/phpthumbnails/) for a thumbnailing function. Or download all images at once and resize them all at once.

Now you are at the last step just show your thumbnail and link to the high-res images.